# Combining doubles and strings into a single value?

Tags: xcode, string, double, int, concatenation

Basically i have this code:

```
l11 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Health: %@", chealth, @"Ammo: %@", cammo];
```

Where l11 is a NSString and i want it equal to "Health " + double chealth + "Ammo: " + double cammo.

Right now, it works fine but it says null where the doubles are supposed to be even though they are declared and I tested this. How can this be fixed?

Comment: chealth and cammo are of type double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming chealth and cammo are of type double:

```
l11 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Health: %f Ammo: %f", chealth, cammo];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to format a double (`%f`) as an object (`%@`). Read [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).